# clean way to read out id in a request path in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, path, request

I have a request that comes in like this: `api/v1/photos/1/media/2`

"1" and "2" are ids I need to read out in the controller. "2" I can get through the parameters: `params["id"]`.

What's a clean way to read out the first id "1"? I can get the entire path with `request.path` or `request.url`. But since this returns a string I would have to do some string manipulation to get to the id. Is there a better/cleaner way to do this?

The routes are defined so:

```
resources :photos do
  member do
    resources :media
      member do
      end 
  end
end
```

i tried printing out `params` but it only had the second id and the action.

Comment: just ruby, or rails as well? it will depend on your routes. with nested resources you get `params["photo_id"]`. you can also just inspect `params` and see what you can access.

Comment: In Rails, you typically define [routes](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) with placeholder, e.g. `api/v1/photos/:photo_id/media/:id`. In this example, you'd have `1` as `params["photo_id"]`, but it depends on your actual route. Just inspect the content of `params` and it should be obvious.

Comment: params only shows the action in addition but nothing else. I tried `params["photo_id"]` but was empty

Comment: upated my question

Comment: Try `bin/rails routes` or http://localhost:3000/rails/info/routes – it should show the available routes. What does it return for your your route?

Comment: when you nest `resources` under `member` you get `:id` param for both.  either remove `member` block or add `resources :media, param: :media_id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried what params return if routes are like this?

```
resources :photos do
   resources :media
end
```